# How to round a Pandas `DatetimeIndex`?

Tags: date, datetime, numpy, pandas, date-format

I have a `pandas.DatetimeIndex`, e.g.:

```
pd.date_range('2012-1-1 02:03:04.000',periods=3,freq='1ms')
>>> [2012-01-01 02:03:04, ..., 2012-01-01 02:03:04.002000]
```

I would like to round the dates (`Timestamp`s) to the nearest second. How do I do that? The expected result is similar to:

```
[2012-01-01 02:03:04.000000, ..., 2012-01-01 02:03:04.000000]
```

Is it possible to accomplish this by rounding a Numpy `datetime64[ns]` to seconds without changing the `dtype` `[ns]`?

```
np.array(['2012-01-02 00:00:00.001'],dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

Comment: @hayden, see my edit. I just want to round to the nearest second.

Comment: `date_range` defaults to day frequency, I assume you meant to have `pd.date_range('2012-1-1 00:00.000',periods=2, freq='S')`

Comment: @MattiJohn, see my correction. I meant the *same* second to repeat.

Comment: Good solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24479577/2662901)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Update: if you're doing this to a DatetimeIndex / datetime64 column a better way is to use `np.round` directly rather than via an apply/map:

```
np.round(dtindex_or_datetime_col.astype(np.int64), -9).astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

Old answer (with some more explanation):

Whilst @Matti's answer is clearly the correct way to deal with your situation, I thought I would add an answer how you might round a Timestamp to the nearest second:

```
from pandas.lib import Timestamp

t1 = Timestamp('2012-1-1 00:00:00')
t2 = Timestamp('2012-1-1 00:00:00.000333')

In [4]: t1
Out[4]: <Timestamp: 2012-01-01 00:00:00>

In [5]: t2
Out[5]: <Timestamp: 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000333>

In [6]: t2.microsecond
Out[6]: 333

In [7]: t1.value
Out[7]: 1325376000000000000L

In [8]: t2.value
Out[8]: 1325376000000333000L

# Alternatively: t2.value - t2.value % 1000000000
In [9]: long(round(t2.value, -9)) # round milli-, micro- and nano-seconds
Out[9]: 1325376000000000000L

In [10]: Timestamp(long(round(t2.value, -9)))
Out[10]: <Timestamp: 2012-01-01 00:00:00>
```

Hence you can apply this to the entire index:

```
def to_the_second(ts):
    return Timestamp(long(round(ts.value, -9)))

dtindex.map(to_the_second)
```

Comment: It seems like `1000000` should be replaced with `1000000000`.

Comment: Importantly, I would like to do it on a `DatetimeIndex`.

Comment: @user1579844 you're right of course! I forgot about milli-seconds... whoops! I have corrected this and added how to apply this to the entire dt_index.

Comment: "Alternatively: t2.value - t2.value % 1000000000"

This will round t2 down I believe, not to nearest.

Answer (score 15):

`round()` method was added for DatetimeIndex, Timestamp, TimedeltaIndex and Timedelta in pandas 0.18.0. Now we can do the following:

```
In[114]: index = pd.DatetimeIndex([pd.Timestamp('2012-01-01 02:03:04.000'), pd.Timestamp('2012-01-01 02:03:04.002'), pd.Timestamp('20130712 02:03:04.500'), pd.Timestamp('2012-01-01 02:03:04.501')])

In[115]: index.values
Out[115]: 
array(['2012-01-01T02:03:04.000000000', '2012-01-01T02:03:04.002000000',
       '2013-07-12T02:03:04.500000000', '2012-01-01T02:03:04.501000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')

In[116]: index.round('S')
Out[116]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2012-01-01 02:03:04', '2012-01-01 02:03:04',
               '2013-07-12 02:03:04', '2012-01-01 02:03:05'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

`round()` accepts frequency parameter. String aliases for it are listed [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases).

Answer (score 4):

There is little point in changing the index itself - since you can just generate using `date_range` with the desired frequency parameter as in your question.

I assume what you are trying to do is change the frequency of a Time Series that contains data, in which case you can use `resample` ([documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#up-and-downsampling)). For example if you have the following time series:

```
dt_index = pd.date_range('2012-1-1 00:00.001',periods=3, freq='1ms')
ts = pd.Series(randn(3), index=dt_index)


2012-01-01 00:00:00           0.594618
2012-01-01 00:00:00.001000    0.874552
2012-01-01 00:00:00.002000   -0.700076
Freq: L
```

Then you can change the frequency to seconds using resample, specifying how you want to aggregate the values (mean, sum etc.):

```
ts.resample('S', how='sum')

2012-01-01 00:00:00    0.594618
2012-01-01 00:00:01    0.174475
Freq: S
```

Comment: This eliminates some of the rows. I would like only to *change* the index value by rounding it to the nearest second.

Comment: ah, sorry I hadn't realised you wanted duplicate values. It looks like @hayden's updated answer will do what you want

Answer (score 3):

For more general rounding, you can make use of the fact that Pandas `Timestamp` objects mostly use the standard library `datetime.datetime` API, including the [`datetime.datetime.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) method.

So, to solve your microsecond rounding problem, you could do:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

times = pd.date_range('2012-1-1 02:03:04.499',periods=3,freq='1ms')
# Add 5e5 microseconds and truncate to simulate rounding
times_rounded = [(x + datetime.timedelta(microseconds=5e5)).replace(microsecond=0) for x in times]

from IPython.display import display
print('Before:')
display(list(times))
print('After:')
display(list(times_rounded))
```

Output:

```
Before:
[Timestamp('2012-01-01 02:03:04.499000', offset='L'),
 Timestamp('2012-01-01 02:03:04.500000', offset='L'),
 Timestamp('2012-01-01 02:03:04.501000', offset='L')]
After:
[Timestamp('2012-01-01 02:03:04', offset='L'),
 Timestamp('2012-01-01 02:03:05', offset='L'),
 Timestamp('2012-01-01 02:03:05', offset='L')]
```

You can use the same technique to, e.g., round to the nearest day (as long as you're not concerned about leap seconds and the like):

```
times = pd.date_range('2012-1-1 08:00:00', periods=3, freq='4H')
times_rounded = [(x + datetime.timedelta(hours=12)).replace(hour=0, second=0, microsecond=0) for x in times]
```

Inspired by this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19718411/1410871