# Pandas: Timestamp index rounding to the nearest 5th minute

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df` with the usual timestamps as an index:

```
    2011-04-01 09:30:00
    2011-04-01 09:30:10
    ...
    2011-04-01 09:36:20
    ...
    2011-04-01 09:37:30
```

How can I create a column to this dataframe with the same timestamp but rounded to the nearest 5th minute interval? Like this:

```
    index                 new_col
    2011-04-01 09:30:00   2011-04-01 09:35:00        
    2011-04-01 09:30:10   2011-04-01 09:35:00
    2011-04-01 09:36:20   2011-04-01 09:40:00
    2011-04-01 09:37:30   2011-04-01 09:40:00
```

Comment: Many of these answers are the more consise and you need only change `5mins` in place of `15min` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32344533/how-do-i-round-datetime-column-to-nearest-quarter-hour

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[The `round_to_5min(t)` solution using `timedelta` arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24479736) is correct but complicated and very slow. Instead make use of the nice `Timstamp` in pandas:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

ns5min=5*60*1000000000   # 5 minutes in nanoseconds 
pd.to_datetime(((df.index.astype(np.int64) // ns5min + 1 ) * ns5min))
```

Let's compare the speed:

```
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2014', '1/2/2014', freq='S')

print len(rng)
# 86401

# ipython %timeit 
%timeit pd.to_datetime(((rng.astype(np.int64) // ns5min + 1 ) * ns5min))
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.01 ms per loop

%timeit rng.map(round_to_5min)
# 1 loops, best of 3: 1.03 s per loop
```

Just about 1000 times faster!

Comment: Be careful when you are dealing with daylight saving time: not all days have the same length, and your approach may fail. I recommend using offsets: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects

Comment: @Marius Ion: No need to be careful here. The length of the day is irrelevant. If the DatetimeIndex has a timezone, the `astype`  operation converts to UTC. Just convert the result back to your timezone then (e.g. with `tz_localize("UTC").tz_convert("US/Eastern")`)

Comment: Note that to round to the nearest 5min instead of rounding up, it is slightly more complicated - maybe worth adding it to your answer ? I paste my code here but obviously it will look nicer in the answer as comments dont have formatting :(
******
pd.to_datetime(
    ((rng.astype(np.int64) // ns5min) * ns5min)                                # round down
    + (((rng.astype(np.int64) % ns5min) > (ns5min / 2)) * ns5min)  # add 5min if needed
)

Answer (score 24):

One could easily use the round function of pandas

```
df["timestamp_column"].dt.round("5min")
```

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32344533/how-do-i-round-datetime-column-to-nearest-quarter-hour?noredirect=1&lq=1) for more details

Comment: Yes.  Using `%timeit` I got: 130 µs ± 2.53 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

Comment: This is actually the most accurate and logical. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can try something like this:

```
def round_to_5min(t):
    delta = datetime.timedelta(minutes=t.minute%5, 
                               seconds=t.second, 
                               microseconds=t.microsecond)
    t -= delta
    if delta > datetime.timedelta(0):
        t += datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
    return t

df['new_col'] = df.index.map(round_to_5min)
```

Comment: that looks good but when I test it on my data I see:

`2011-04-01 09:32:10 -> 2011-04-01 09:30:00`
`2011-04-01 09:32:20 -> 2011-04-01 09:30:00`
`2011-04-01 09:32:30 -> 2011-04-01 09:35:00`
`2011-04-01 09:32:40 -> 2011-04-01 09:35:00`
they should all be 2011-04-01 09:35:00

Comment: Ah, in your question you mentioned round to the 'nearest' 5 minutes, but I see from your data you want to round up to the next 5 minutes. I've fixed the answer, thanks. I'm assuming you want 9:30:00:00 to round to 9:30:00:00 rather than 9:35:00:00, otherwise you can just always add the 5 minutes.

Comment: would you how I could select the hours and minutes from my new_col? For instance I am trying to do this: `datetime.datetime.hour(df.new_col)` so that I can have a new colum just with the hour and that's not working

Comment: Same sort of operation: `df['hour'] = df.new_col.map(lambda t: t.hour)`

Comment: Great thanks! I really need to learn all the possibilities with map

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but with datetime64p[ns] timestamps.

I used:

```
def round_to_5min(t):
    """ This function rounds a timedelta timestamp to the nearest 5-min mark"""
    t = datetime.datetime(t.year, t.month, t.day, t.hour, t.minute - t.minute%5, 0)  
    return t
```

followed by the the 'map' function