# Split dataframe into many sub-dataframes based on timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I have a large csv with the following format:

```
timestamp,name,age
2020-03-01 00:00:01,nick
2020-03-01 00:00:01,john
2020-03-01 00:00:02,nick
2020-03-01 00:00:02,john
2020-03-01 00:00:04,peter
2020-03-01 00:00:05,john
2020-03-01 00:00:10,nick
2020-03-01 00:00:12,john
2020-03-01 00:00:54,hank
2020-03-01 00:01:03,peter
```

I load csv into a dataframe with:

```
df = pd.read_csv("/home/test.csv")
```

and then I want to create multiple dataframes every 2 seconds. For example:

df1 contains:

```
2020-03-01 00:00:01,nick
2020-03-01 00:00:01,john
2020-03-01 00:00:02,nick
2020-03-01 00:00:02,john
```

df2 contains :

```
2020-03-01 00:00:04,peter
2020-03-01 00:00:05,john
```

and so on.

I achieve to split timestamps with command below:

```
full_idx = pd.date_range(start=df['timestamp'].min(), end = df['timestamp'].max(), freq ='0.2T')
```

but how I can store these spitted dataframes? How can I split a dataset based on timestamps into multiple dataframes?

Comment: How you want to store it? In a dict?

Comment: I want to store Inside a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [`.resample()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)?

```
#first loading your data
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> df = pd.read_csv('dates.csv', index_col='timestamp', parse_dates=True)
>>> df.head()
                      name  age
timestamp
2020-03-01 00:00:01   nick  NaN
2020-03-01 00:00:01   john  NaN
2020-03-01 00:00:02   nick  NaN
2020-03-01 00:00:02   john  NaN
2020-03-01 00:00:04  peter  NaN

#resampling it at a frequency of 2 seconds
>>> resampled = df.resample('2s')
>>> type(resampled)
<class 'pandas.core.resample.DatetimeIndexResampler'>

#iterating over the resampler object and storing the sliced dfs in a dictionary
>>> df_dict = {}
>>> for i, (timestamp,df) in enumerate(resampled):
>>>     df_dict[i] = df
>>> df_dict[0]
                     name  age
timestamp
2020-03-01 00:00:01  nick  NaN
2020-03-01 00:00:01  john  NaN
```

---

Now for some explanation...

`resample()` is great for rebinning `DataFrames` based on time (I use it often for downsampling time series data), but it can be used simply to cut up the `DataFrame`, as you want to do.  Iterating over the `resampler` object produced by `df.resample()` returns a tuple of (`name of the bin`,`df corresponding to that bin`): e.g. the first tuple is (timestamp of the first second,data corresponding to the first 2 seconds).  So to get the `DataFrame`s out, we can loop over this object and store them somewhere, like a `dict`.

Note that this will produce *every* 2-second interval from the start to the end of the data, so many will be empty given your data.  But you can add a step to filter those out if needed.

Additionally, you could manually assign each sliced `DataFrame` to a variable, but this would be cumbersome (you would probably need to write a line for each 2 second bin, rather than a single small loop).  Rather with a `dictionary`, you can still associate each `DataFrame` with a callable name.  You could also use an `OrderedDict` or `list` or whatever collection.

---

A couple points on your script:

- setting `freq` to "0.2T" is 12 seconds (`.2 *60`); you can rather
  do `freq="2s"`
- The example `df` and `df2` are "out of phase," by that I mean one is binned in 2 seconds starting on odd numbers (1-2 seconds), while one is starting on evens (4-5 seconds).  So the `date_range` you mentioned wouldn't create those bins, it would create `dfs` from either 0-1s, 2-3s, 4-5s... OR 1-2s,3-4s,5-6s,... depending on which timestamp it started on.

For the latter point, you can use the `base` argument of `.resample()` to set the "phase" of the resampling.  So in the case above, `base=0` would start bins on even numbers, and `base=1` would start bins on odds.

This is assuming you are okay with that type of binning - if you really want 1-2 seconds and 4-5 seconds to be in different bins, you would have to do something more complicated I believe.

Comment: df = pd.read_csv('dates.csv', index_col='timestamp', parse_dates=True) seems to remove timestamp column. how to prevent it?

Comment: You can remove the `index_col='timestamp'` argument - this will leave that column in the `df`.  But the data is not gone; using `index_col`, the `timestamp` becomes the index (row labels) of the `DataFrame`, you can still access the values by using `df.index`.  It's common to have time series data in the index, and `resample()` automatically works on the `index` (but you can change this by using the `on` argument)

Answer (score 1):

Probably that question can help us: [Pandas: Timestamp index rounding to the nearest 5th minute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24479577/pandas-timestamp-index-rounding-to-the-nearest-5th-minute)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

ns2sec=2*1000000000   # 2 seconds in nanoseconds 
# next we round our timestamp to every 2nd second with rounding down
timestamp_rounded = df['timestamp'].astype(np.int64) // ns2sec
df['full_idx'] = pd.to_datetime(((timestamp_rounded - timestamp_rounded % 2) * ns2sec))

# store array for each unique value of your idx
store_array = []
for value in df['full_idx'].unique():
    store_array.append(df[df['full_idx']==value][['timestamp', 'name', 'age']])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why do you use .unique()?

Comment: @e7lT2P we have new column with values 2020-03-01 00:00:00, 2020-03-01 00:00:02, 2020-03-01 00:00:04 and  so on. We want to split your df one time that your dict has only one df1, one df2 and so on. We do that by getting unique values and using filter ```df['full_idx']==value```