# Convert time format in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a string object in this format 2014-12-08 09:30:00.066000 but I want to convert to datetime variable. I also want this to be less granular- I want it to be just in the order of second for example

2014-12-08 09:30:00.066000 to 2014-12-08 09:30:00

I am trying to use pd.to_datetime function but it's not working for me. Anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Which library is pd.to_datetime... ? pandas?

Comment: Can you show how you were using pd.to_datetime?  That should work fine.  If for some reason it won't work, you can apply a strptime function to the str series.  https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Comment: Sorry for not being very clear. pd.to_datetime is from pandas. And what I meant by not working is that I want my timestamp to be less granular. In my example, it is in the order of microseconds, but I want it to show only up to the order of second. My thought was that pd.to_datetime will automatically convert to the order of seconds. Also, what if I want it to show up to the order of minute only, is there any way to do this? This is because in the end, I want to do the aggregate sum of other variables minute by minute. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

See this:

[How to round a Pandas `DatetimeIndex`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785932/how-to-round-a-pandas-datetimeindex)

```
from pandas.lib import Timestamp

def to_the_second(ts):
    return Timestamp(long(round(ts.value, -9)))

df['My_Date_Column'].apply(to_the_second)
```